# Что возвращает return *this c++

Tags: c++, ооп, указатели, ссылки, перегрузка-операторов

**return *this** возвращает сам объект , а  **MyClass** **&**  преобразует как ссылку объекта (ну или  **MyClass &** указывает что **return *this** (то есть объект) есть ссылкой)?

Объясните что и как а то я запутался

```
MyClass & operator = (const MyClass& other) 
{ 
// Код...
// Код...
// Код...
// Код...
   return *this; 
}
```

Comment: Если бы возвращаемый тип был `MyClass`, то вы возвращали бы копию текущего объекта. А так возвращаете ссылку на объект.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat как выглядит эта ссылка?

Answer (score 2):

Возвращает ссылку на вызывающий объект для последовательного вызова методов.

Чтобы не путаться, нужно понимать, как могут передаваться объекты в C++. А передаваться они могут: **по значению**, **по указателю** и **по ссылке**.

Т.к. `this` - указатель, то его сначала нужно разыменовать. Ссылка ведет себя точно также как и сам объект, его оригинал. Поэтому возможно и такое:

```cpp
object.method() = variable;
```

В твоём случае метод - `operator=()`. У перегруженных операторов ассоциативность сохраняется, поэтому всё будет работать как нужно:

```cpp
object_1 = object_2 = object_3;
object_1.operator=(object_2.operator=(object_3));
```

Тогда как, например, `operator+()` будет работать по умолчанию с обратной ассоциативностью:

```cpp
object_1 + object_2 + object_3;
object_1.operator+(object_2).operator+(object_3);
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что термин "по указателю" - от лукавого. Это просто передача указателя по значению.

Comment: @Mikhailo, так и есть, но передача указателя выделена в отдельную категорию, особенно в чистом Си. Ведь в нём нет ссылок. И в K&R про указатели так и говориться, что они нужны для передачи массивов по ссылке, т.к. массивы по значению не передаются (если только их не завернуть в структуру). Вот Си++ и наследует от чистого Си все эти премудрости, и это правильно, ведь Си++ не навязывает ООП, как это делают Ява и Шарп, и позволяет кодить в структурном стиле.